# Angularfire2 custom authentication

Tags: authentication, angularfire2

I creating a website which has register link multiple auth providers and custom token as well. I also using AngularFire2 to communicate between Angular2 and Firebase but seem it doesn't have method similar with Firebase, e.g:

`var ref = new Firebase("https://<YOUR-FIREBASE-APP>.firebaseio.com/");
ref.authWithCustomToken(AUTH_TOKEN, function(error, authData) {`

Anyone can show up to me how can deal with issue?

Answer (score 3):

To authenticate using a custom token, you can call AngularFire2's `login` method with the following configuration options:

```ts
angularFire.auth.login(AUTH_TOKEN, {
  provider: AuthProviders.Custom,
  method: AuthMethods.CustomToken
});
```

Internally, this will call Firebase's [`signInWithCustomToken`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#signInWithCustomToken) method.

Comment: Thank you. So I still use FirebaseTokenGenerator for custom token, isn't it?

Comment: If you are talking about [this](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-token-generator-node), then no. Apparently, it's [not for Firebase 3](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-token-generator-node#firebase-token-generator---nodejs--).

Comment: FYI, login will be removed in version 4. It's already gone in RC1.